# merge to arrays into one state react-native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have tried a lot of things to get this working.

I have the following 2 stats in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 this.state = {
   newArray: [],
   dataStorage: [],
 };
}
```

Then I have a function to handle the parameteres from the TextInputs. I'm creating a new array to add the data and then I want to add it to the existing array.

```
submitHandler(inputValue, inputIdentifier) {
 console.log('inside the submitHandler');

 var newArray = [];
 newArray.push({
  value: inputValue,
  identificer: inputIdentifier.item
 });
 this.setState({newArray: newArray})

 let dataStorage = [this.state.newArray, ...this.state.dictionaryForAddedItems]

 this.setState({dataStorage: dataStorage})

  console.log('her is was inside the newArray' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
  console.log('her is was inside the state.dictionaryForAddedItems' + JSON.stringify(this.state.dataStorage));
```

My logs turn out this way: 
[Log in debug looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdFEx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention exactly what is the problem you are facing but if i understand correctly, you don't see the updated state in your `console.log`.

If this is the case, you should know that `setState` is asynchronous.
You can use the second argument of `setState` which is a callback function.

```
setState({myKey:myVal}, () => {console.log(this.state.myKey)})
```

Here is a fixed version of your code (you could call the `setState` once as well, with 2 keys instead of two calls):

```
submitHandler(inputValue, inputIdentifier) {
    console.log('inside the submitHandler');

    var newArray = [];
    newArray.push({
        value: inputValue,
        identificer: inputIdentifier.item
    });
    this.setState({ newArray: newArray })

    let dataStorage = [newArray, ...this.state.dictionaryForAddedItems]

    this.setState({ dataStorage: dataStorage }, () => {

        console.log('her is was inside the newArray' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
        console.log('her is was inside the state.dictionaryForAddedItems' + JSON.stringify(this.state.dataStorage));
    });
}
```

Comment: My problem is that there is no data in the dataStorage state. In the console log it's only showing the empty array. console.log('her is was inside the state.dictionaryForAddedItems' + JSON.stringify(this.state.dataStorage));

Comment: @MaikenMadsen i've updated my asnwer with your code.  like i said it is set asynchronously. you are setting the state once and depending on it to finish to set it again with the new update, but it didn't finished yet.

Comment: I can see I haven't been so clear in my problem because the function is called several times and the data in dictionaryForAddedItems is overwritten every time the function is called. I wish add the data from newArray to the existing data in dictionaryForAddedItems .-

Comment: i don't see any initial state for `dictionaryForAddedItems` in your code though. note that you are logging `this.state.dataStorage`

Comment: Yeah I forgot to copy past it. it's in the constructor to. The reason why i'm logging the dataStorage is because i want the newArray to be merged into the exsisting array of data in dictionaryForAddedItems.

Comment: now I got it. I was able to do this: this.setState({dictionaryForAddedItems: [...this.state.dataStorage]}) before the console logs and now it's adding instead of overwritting. Thanks for your help :-D